# How to associate an existing site column to a list using the REST API

Tags: rest, column

In SharePoint 2013, I have a site column that already exists and I'm trying to associate it to an existing list using the REST API. I found examples on adding a new column to a list using the REST API but no examples on adding an existing site column. Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be achieved by providing the site column's schema when creating a field in the target list.

First, the desired site column's `SchemaXml` property is retrieved using one of the `fields` endpoints:

```
https://<site url>/_api/web/fields('<field guid>')/SchemaXml
https://<site url>/_api/web/fields/GetByTitle('<field title>')/SchemaXml
```

This can then be used in the [`CreateFieldAsXML`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/office/dn600182.aspx#bk_FieldCollectionCreateFieldAsXml) method to add the column to the target list:

```
https://<site url>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<list title>')/fields/createfieldasxml
```

with the `SchemaXml` embedded in the JSON payload:

```
{
    "parameters": {
        "__metadata": {
            "type": "SP.XmlSchemaFieldCreationInformation"
        },
        "SchemaXml": "<Field Type=...></Field>"
    }
}
```

Checking the `SourceID` property of the newly created field confirms that it matches with that of the site column. Also, the site column is no longer listed when attempting to manually add it using the *Add Columns from Site Columns* page in the list's settings.