# Is it possible to add existing site column to list using REST?

Tags: 2013, development, rest, column

Is it possible to add an existing site column to a SharePoint list with **REST**? The MSDN documentation shows that a field can be added using `/fields/addField` but all the examples I have seen just create a new field, which I don't want to do. I find it very hard to believe that it is possible to create a new field but not add an existing one.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/178681/53657)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for bumping old post. I came across this and I was looking for a more complete answer.

Jonathan is right, you create a 'child' field on the list using the site field as a base.

I did it like this (don't do a blind copy please, headers are not included here):

```
pro.createListColumnFromXmlSchema = function(currSite, listName, schemaXml){
// Set the option to addFieldInternalNameHint - 8 to ensure the internal name in the schema xml is not altered.
return $.ajax({
    url: currSite+"_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/fields/createfieldasxml",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "parameters": {
            "__metadata": { "type": "SP.XmlSchemaFieldCreationInformation" },
            "Options": 8,
            "SchemaXml": schemaXml
        }
    })
});
```

}

To first get the schemaXml I do this:

```
pro.addColumnToList = function(currSite,listName,dispName){
var deferred = $.Deferred();
$.get(currSite + "_api/site/RootWeb/Fields/getByTitle('"+dispName+"')/schemaxml").done(function(data){
    var schemaXml = data.d.SchemaXml;
    pro.createListColumnFromXmlSchema(currSite, listName, schemaXml).done(function(data){
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }).fail( function(arguments){ deferred.reject(arguments); } );
}).fail( function(arguments){ deferred.reject(arguments); } );
return deferred.promise();
```

};